# C# how to print multiple crystal reports as one?

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I have a report with some parameters that are filled by code, right now the program, load, fill and print the report in a loop

```
// get list that contains reports data, every item in list is a report
List<Etiquetas> etiquetas = SolicitudBL.GetEtiquetas(id);
foreach(Etiqueta e in etiquetas)
{
   // load report and pass data
   // report only shows paramaters value, dont use data from database
   ReportDocument report = GetReport("reportName", e);
   report.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
}
```

this works but takes to much time to print between reports
is there a way to print all the reportdocuments at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there is a waiting time between the prints is that Crystal needs time to query the database and render each report. You can export the reports to PDFs and then print them. Total time will be the same , but there will be no big pauses while printing.